# How to simplify Big-O expressions

Tags: algorithm, big-o, algebra

I'm trying to understand the algebra behind Big-O expressions. I have gone through several questions but still don't have a very clear idea how it's done.

When dealing with powers do we always omit the lower powers, for example:

```
O(10n^4-n^2-10) = O(10n^4)
```

What difference does it make when multiplication is involved? For example:

`O(2n^3+10^2n) * O(n) = O(2n^3)` ??

And finally, how do we deal with logs? For example:

```
O(n2) + O(5*log(n))
```

I think we try to get rid of all constants and lower powers. I'm not sure how logarithms are involved in the simplification and what difference a multiplication sign would do. Thank you.

Comment: Technically: big-O is a class of functions. I don't believe it makes sense to add or multiply them. I suspect you meant `O((2n^3+10^2n) * n))`, but this just simplifies to `O(2n^4+10^2n^2)` in a way that has nothing to do with big-O, and then we're just back to taking the highest power (and omitting constant factors). So I'm not really sure what your question is.

Comment: What do you mean by 10^2n - is this (10^2)n or 10^(2n)? They are very different.

Answer (score 4):

Big-O expressions are more closely related to Calculus, specifically limits, than they are to algebraic concepts/rules. The easiest way I've found to think about expressions like the examples you've provided, is to start by plugging in a small number, and then a really large number, and observe how the result changes:

```
Expression: O(10n^4-n^2-10)
use n = 2: O(10(2^4) - 2^2 - 10)
           O(10 * 16 - 4 - 10) = 146
use n = 100: O(10(100^4) - 100^2- 10)
             O(10(100,000,000) - 10,000 - 10) = 999,989,990
```

What you can see from this, is that the n^4 term overpowers all other terms in the expression. Therefore, this algorithm would be denoted as having a run-time of O(n^4).

So yes, your assumptions are correct, that you should *generally* go with the highest power, drop constants, and drop order-1 terms.

Logarithms are effectively "undoing" exponentiation. Because of this, they will reduce the overall O-run-time of an algorithm. However, when they are added against exponential run-times, they generally get overruled by the larger order term. In the example you provided, if we again evaluate using real numbers:

```
Expression: O(n^2) + O(5*log(n))
use n=2:    O(2^2) + O(5*log(2))
            O(4) + O(3.4657) = 7.46
use n=100:  O(100^2) + O(5*log(100))
            O(10,000) + O(23.02) = 10,023
```

You will notice that although the logarithm term is increasing, it isn't a great gain compared to the increase in n's size. However, the n^2 term is still generating a massive increase compared to the increase in n's size. Because of this, the Big O of these expressions combined would still boil down to: O(n^2).

If you're interested in further reading about the mathematics side of this, you may want to check out this post: https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/algebra/page/algebra.html